# Php MYSQL query varias tabelas

Tags: php, mysql

Boas, estou com dificuldade em mostrar os dados de uma Base de dados utilizando 3 tabelas.

```
<?php
include("conectar.php");

$quantidade = 1;
$pagina = (isset($_GET['pagina'])) ? (int)$_GET['pagina'] : 1;
$inicio = ($quantidade * $pagina)-$quantidade;  
$sql = "Select * From tb_trabalhador order by id asc LIMIT $inicio, $quantidade";
$qr = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
    while($exibe = mysql_fetch_array($qr)){
```

Tenho mais 2 tabelas para exibir os dados que lá estão .
Fiz o teste só com duas tabelas e tambem não me exibe os dados inseridos

```
 SELECT * FROM tb_trabalhador
 INNER JOIN tb_detalhe_trabalhador ON Tb_trabalhador.id     =tb_detalhe_trabalhador.tb_trabalhador_id;
```

Experimentei o Left e o Right e exibe os dados das respectivas tabelas.
Será que me conseguem ajudar neste problema?

Comment: nesta páginas tem alguns exemplos http://blog.thiagobelem.net/relacionamento-de-tabelas-no-mysql/

Comment: Por mais que alguns entenderam seu problema, não está claro o que você está perguntando. Deixe registrado o que você está precisando.

Comment: Já fiz alterações e espero que esteja mais claro agora a minha duvida

Comment: @user3253195 Até onde é possível entender, você quer fazer um join com as 3 tabelas. O problema não seria o código PHP. Creio que a questão como um todo não está muito clara pelas palavras usadas, tal como o termo "chamar tabelas". Além disso, você diz que o resultado da sua tentativa foi 0 (zero), mas o que isso significa? Zero registros? Soma igual a zero? Cadê sua tentativa de join? Acho que sua pergunta foi fechada porque as pessoas não conseguiram interpretar o que você disse. Se entendi corretamente, sugiro editar mais uma vez, inclusive o título, para algo relacionado a SQL e Joins.

Answer (score 3):

Use um join para para juntar as tabelas e acessar todos os campos que você precisa:

```
SELECT * FROM tb_trabalhador as t
INNER JOIN tb_equipamentos as e ON t.id = e.trabalhador_id
INNER JOIN tb_detalhe_trabalhador as d ON t.id = d.tb_trabalhador_id
```

no lugar do astericos * coloque os campos necessarios no formato `tabela.nome_do_campo` ou `alias.nome_do_campo`

Ex:

```
SELECT e.marca, e.modelo, t.nome, t.matricula, d.outro_campo FROM ....
INNER ....
```

Conteúdo relacionado:
[diferença entre INNER X OUTER](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/qual-e-a-diferenca-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join)

Comment: não precisa do inner join

Comment: precisa do que no lugar? não entendi seu comentário

Comment: Fazer um select para fazer o outro não é viável quando se pode usar as junções @Silvio Andorinha. O banco vai trabalhar bem mais rápido com os `join` do que separado igual no link que você postou para ele no comentário. Porém é uma forma de se fazer também, fica a critério dele.

Comment: @lionbtt veja minha resposta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6706/php-query-varias-tabelas/6715#6715

Comment: so uma questão.
A seguir aos "AS" as letras são correspondestes ao que?

Comment: `AS` é para especificar um alias não é obrigatório em alguns bancos serve apenas evidenciar a abreviatura.

Comment: Testei o INNER JOIN e o resultado é em branco. LEFT, Right so me mostra uma das tabelas. Existe mais alguma solução?

Answer (score 1):

Para exemplificar o uso do JOIN igual o @perdeu falou, segue

```
<?php
include("conectar.php");

$quantidade = 1;
$pagina = (isset($_GET['pagina'])) ? (int)$_GET['pagina'] : 1;
$inicio = ($quantidade * $pagina)-$quantidade;  
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tb_trabalhador as t ".
        " INNER JOIN tb_equipamentos as e ON t.id = e.trabalhador_id "
        " INNER JOIN tb_detalhe_trabalhador as d ON t.id = d.tb_trabalhador_id order by id asc LIMIT $inicio, $quantidade";
$qr = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
  while($exibe = mysql_fetch_array($qr)){
```

Se a tabela `tp_equipamento` não for sempre obrigatório, ou seja, pode ser que não tenha dado relacionado a `tp_trabalhador`, você terá que utilizar o `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: não precisa do inner join

Comment: so uma questão. A seguir aos "AS" as letras são correspondestes ao que?

Answer (score 0):

Jeito bem simples utilizando a junção na clausula `WHERE`

```
<?php
include("conectar.php");

$quantidade = 1;
$pagina = (isset($_GET['pagina'])) ? (int)$_GET['pagina'] : 1;
$inicio = ($quantidade * $pagina)-$quantidade;  
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tb_trabalhador as t, tb_equipamentos e , tb_detalhe_trabalhador d ".
       " WHERE t.id = e.trabalhador_id AND t.id = d.tb_trabalhador_id ".
       " order by id asc LIMIT $inicio, $quantidade";
$qr = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
  while($exibe = mysql_fetch_array($qr)){
```

Comment: @perdeu olha aqui sem o inner join

Comment: Ok, um outro jeito de se fazer..Porém, podia publicar a resposta ao invés de comentar.

Comment: Essa forma de juntar as tabelas era feita em bancos de dados antigos (sintaxe ansi-89) a que usa o `join` é mais nova (sintaxe ansi-92), acredito que deixar o `WHERE` somente para filtros é mais legivel que usa-lo para fazer junções e filtros.